# How do I configure a ASAPI DLL for Delphi in Apache 2.X?

Tags: delphi, apache, dll, isapi

I'm trying to understand ISAPI as run under Apache 2.x.  I've created a simple DLL using Delphi XE to test with based on a tutorial I found.

I've added these lines to my Apache httpd.conf file.

```
ScriptAlias /Delphi/ "C:/Delphi/bin/"
<Directory "C:/Delphi/bin/">
  AddHandler isapi-handler .dll    
  AllowOverride None
  Options ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The isapi_module is loaded.

I've placed the DLL in C:\Delphi\bin.

When I call it with the following URL (case is correct);
    http://127.0.0.1/Delphi/ISAPI_Test1.dll

I get a 403 error and the Apache Error Log has this line.

```
... [error] [client 127.0.0.1] attempt to invoke directory as script: C:/Delphi/bin/
```

I expect the dll to simply use the default handler:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  begin
    Response.SendRedirect (Request.Referer);
  end;
```

Question 1: What is my specific issue here?
Question 2: Can anybody point me to a step by step tutorial or book for getting a basic skelton working? I've got too many holes in my understanding at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: I have done a lot of work using Apache but as a "Shared Module" and not "CGI" mode.  Have you tried the "Shared Module" approach?  Is there a link on the web for the "tutorial I found"??

Comment: This post must be moved to ServerFault (where it is indeed duplicated), see my answer.

Comment: @M Schenkel The tutorial is older and goes back to Delphi 5.  http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc060901a.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this subject, look at serverfault.com, for example, this question: [apache attempt to invoke directory as script](https://serverfault.com/questions/107467/attempt-to-invoke-directory-as-script)

Comment: Thank you. I also had to change my options for the redirect to work.  Options ExecCGI +Indexes